# Best way to sort files by type depending on mimetype

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, sorting, mime-types

Here is my challenge:

I have a file input with which I can select multiple files. I can easily get access to the mimetype of each of the selected files and manipulate them before they are added to the upload queue. What i want to do is to sort those files into 6 categories.

I have this objects :

```
files:{
   audio_type:[],
   video_type:[],
   image_type:[],
   pdf_type:[],
   text_type:[],
   other_type:[]
}
```

For each file added with the file input, i want to be able to put it inside the right category node of my files object above.

The thing is, for each category, i only accept certain mimetype. For example in "audio_type" only the mime types equal to "audio/mpeg" or "audio/wav" should be push, if the file's mimetype is not one of those, it is pushed inside "other_type"

I came up with several basic solution, for example with a regexp " if mimetype begins with image/* put it inside the 'image_type' object", but maybe there is a better / faster / scalable method to do so ? Plus this method does not consider my requirements on some mimetype.

I have the big picture here and i should be able to do it by myself, but not in the cleanest way possible I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object as hash table for the filetypes, like

```
var types = { 
    "audio/mpeg": "audio_type",
    "audio/wav": "audio_type",
    // ...
    default:  "other_type"
}
```

Usage:

```
upload.files[types[object.filetype] || types.default].push(object);
```

Comment: Thank you i'm gonna go with this, can't think of a better way to do it !